# Apache Ignite cluster setup

Tags: java, ignite

I have been trying to setup a cluster using Apache ignite. This cluster will have cache and will also implement service grid.

I want to dynamically assign roles to each node based on the node startup and connection to cluster.

Something like, if node 1 is up set it as cache and if we have 2 nodes that hold the cache then deploy the service on the third node.

The code base is same for all nodes.

Is this possible to achieve? How can it be done?

Any help will be appreciated.

Comment: Hi and welcome to SO. How can something be done is not the kind of a question you ask around here. 1) Make your own research (in google). 2) Try to do it yourself. 3)If you fail, come and show us the code, we will try to help

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Apache Ignite assumes that all nodes are homogenous. You can have node attributes, but relying on a specific node to do a specific task is uncommon.

You can have your own code alongside Apache Ignite (which is embeddable) to implement that workflow.

Answer (score 0):

Yes, it can be done using Node Filters:
https://www.gridgain.com/docs/latest/developers-guide/configuring-caches/managing-data-distribution

There is an AttributeNodeFilter that can done this without additional coding:
https://www.gridgain.com/docs/latest/developers-guide/configuring-caches/managing-data-distribution#filtering-nodes-by-attributes